# Shadowed Final Fields

Tags: java, inheritance, field, final

So i am trying to generate a house(at this point a very simple house) and I have this Class:

```
public class Probability {
    public final int MinWindows = 0;
    public final int MaxWindows = 0;
    //double values represend the percent chance for a specific attribute to 
    //generate
    public final double hasBackDoor = 0;
    public final double hasSecondFloor = 0;
    public final double hasChimny = 0;
    public final double hasGarage = 0;
    public final double hasPorch = 0;
}
```

This class is then inherited by subclasses for different types of houses:

```
public class LowClassHouseProbability extends Probability{
    public final int MinWindows = 5;
    public final int MaxWindows = 10;
    public final double hasBackDoor = 55.0;
    public final double hasSecondFloor = 10.0;
    public final double hasChimny = 5.5;
    public final double hasGarage = 30.0;
    public final double hasPorch = 60.0;
}

public class MiddleClassHouseProbability extends Probability{
    public final int MinWindows = 20;
    public final int MaxWindows = 50;
    public final double hasBackDoor = 80.0;
    public final double hasSecondFloor = 70.0;
    public final double hasChimny = 10.0;
    public final double hasGarage = 90.0;
    public final double hasPorch = 85.0;
}

public class UpperClassHouseProbability extends Probability{
    public final int MinWindows = 50;
    public final int MaxWindows = 100;
    public final double hasBackDoor = 100.0;
    public final double hasSecondFloor = 100.0;
    public final double hasChimny = 80.0;
    public final double hasGarage = 99.0;
    public final double hasPorch = 100.0;
}
```

So all of the subclasses of Probability shadow all of its fields which in my opinioin looks sloppy and is kind of annoying to read, however i need them to extend Probability because it would make it easyer when i actually have to use the object, because it looks nicer doing this:

```
public class House {
    public House(Probability prob){

    }
}
```

Than if i did not have a Probability class and did this:

```
public class House {
    public House(LowClassHouseProbability prob){

    }
    public House(MiddleClassHouseProbability prob){

    }
    public House(UpperClassHouseProbability prob){

    }
}
```

And this would only get worse with the more sub-classes that I create.
So my question is is there a better way of doing this that I'm not thinking of, or do i just have to do it one way or the other of the two solutions that I thought of.

Comment: Fields in Java are not polymorphic - so this may not be the way to go.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Oh no, you've introduced a new idea. I bet that one goes in the next C# release.

Comment: @Bathsheba because they are not true/false values. for hasBackDoor for example it is the likely hood of a backdoor generating so if the value is 20.0 there is a 20% chance of a backdoor generating this value will be used later in the house class as a Boolean though

Comment: @Joking313L: Yeah, I read though your code more carefully and realised that.

Comment: Why duplicate the fields to begin with? Why not just pass the subclass values to a constructor in the superclass?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yea i know it already seems like a bad way to code this however now that i have identified a problem i need help solving it not more verification that i have a problem

Comment: @Radiodef because this is just a small sample set of possible fields i want to add more in the future and i feel that making a constructor with a long list of parameters is also sloppy, plus since they are probabilities i want them to be final.

Comment: Why not have a `LowClassHouse`, `MiddleClassHouse` and `UpperClassHouse` all extending `House` and defining their own probabilities? You might find that these house types have more distinctions than just some probabilities.

Comment: @Marvin Yes i could and i didnt know how to do that either i asked a question like that a couple days ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711002/structuring-superclasses but these are attributes that all houses will have not just the subclasses

Comment: You should follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can not override fields from the super class in java those classes dont need at all to define the field..

```
 public class LowClassHouseProbability extends Probability{
     //public final int MinWindows = 50;
     //public final int MaxWindows = 100;
```

those all are final declared so you need to set those in the constructor...

```
LowClassHouseProbability(int minW, int maxW,...){
    super(minW, maxW, ....);

MiddleClassHouseProbability(int minW, int maxW,...){
    super(minW, maxW, ....);

UpperClassHouseProbability(int minW, int maxW,...){
    super(minW, maxW, ....);
```

and in the superclass `Probability` define the constructor:

```
Probability(int minW, int maxW,...){
    MinWindows = minW;
    MaxWindows = maxW;
    // .... etc etc
```

Comment: yes i could do that, however if i use constructors i run into two problems, first isnt really a big deal which is i could accidentally type in a wrong number when creating a new probability object, creating inconsistencies, however the second and more important in my opinion is it decreases the centralization of the code, i want to be able to go to one place and chance one value if i want to change value of a generation attribute i dont want to go to many different constructors changing value.  Unless i am reading your answer wrong in which case could i get some more clarification.

Comment: The constructor approach does not break "centralization" (whatever you mean by that) and is a standard and idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to remove the child classes altogether and define *instances* of the `Probability` class pertinent to your house types, and build a multi-argument *constructor* to facilitate instance construction.

---

Alternatively, you could refactor this into an *interface*:

```
public interface Probability {
    int getMinWindwsMinWindows();
    /*and so on*/
}
```

Then,

```
public class LowClassHouseProbability implements Probability{
{
    @Override
    int getMinWindwsMinWindows()
    {
        return 5;
    }
    /*and so on*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of managing constructors with too many fields can be solved by using a step builder. A step builder works by creating an interface for each step, then having the builder implement all of them. This way after completing each build step, only the next step is available to complete.

Here's an example:

```
package mcve;

public class Probability {
    public final int    minWindows;
    public final int    maxWindows;
    public final double hasBackDoor;
    public final double hasSecondFloor;
    public final double hasChimny;
    public final double hasGarage;
    public final double hasPorch;
    private Probability(final int    minWindows,
                        final int    maxWindows,
                        final double hasBackDoor,
                        final double hasSecondFloor,
                        final double hasChimny,
                        final double hasGarage,
                        final double hasPorch) {
        this.minWindows     = minWindows;
        this.maxWindows     = maxWindows;
        this.hasBackDoor    = hasBackDoor;
        this.hasSecondFloor = hasSecondFloor;
        this.hasChimny      = hasChimny;
        this.hasGarage      = hasGarage;
        this.hasPorch       = hasPorch;
    }

    public static final Probability LOW_CLASS =
        builder().setMinWindows(5)
                 .setMaxWindows(10)
                 .setHasBackDoor(55.0)
                 .setHasSecondFloor(10.0)
                 .setHasChimny(5.5)
                 .setHasGarage(30.0)
                 .setHasPorch(60.0)
                 .build();
    // public static final Probability MIDDLE_CLASS = ...;
    // public static final Probability UPPER_CLASS  = ...;

    public static MinWindowsStep builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public interface MinWindowsStep     { MaxWindowsStep     setMinWindows(int n);        }
    public interface MaxWindowsStep     { HasBackDoorStep    setMaxWindows(int n);        }
    public interface HasBackDoorStep    { HasSecondFloorStep setHasBackDoor(double n);    }
    public interface HasSecondFloorStep { HasChimnyStep      setHasSecondFloor(double n); }
    public interface HasChimnyStep      { HasGarageStep      setHasChimny(double n);      }
    public interface HasGarageStep      { HasPorchStep       setHasGarage(double n);      }
    public interface HasPorchStep       { BuildStep          setHasPorch(double n);       }
    public interface BuildStep          { Probability        build();                     }

    private static final class Builder
    implements MinWindowsStep,
               MaxWindowsStep,
               HasBackDoorStep,
               HasSecondFloorStep,
               HasChimnyStep,
               HasGarageStep,
               HasPorchStep,
               BuildStep {
        private int    minWindows;
        private int    maxWindows;
        private double hasBackDoor;
        private double hasSecondFloor;
        private double hasChimny;
        private double hasGarage;
        private double hasPorch;

        @Override
        public MaxWindowsStep setMinWindows(int minWindows) {
            this.minWindows = minWindows;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public HasBackDoorStep setMaxWindows(int maxWindows) {
            this.maxWindows = maxWindows;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public HasSecondFloorStep setHasBackDoor(double hasBackDoor) {
            this.hasBackDoor = hasBackDoor;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public HasChimnyStep setHasSecondFloor(double hasSecondFloor) {
            this.hasSecondFloor = hasSecondFloor;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public HasGarageStep setHasChimny(double hasChimny) {
            this.hasChimny = hasChimny;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public HasPorchStep setHasGarage(double hasGarage) {
            this.hasGarage = hasGarage;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public BuildStep setHasPorch(double hasPorch) {
            this.hasPorch = hasPorch;
            return this;
        }
        @Override
        public Probability build() {
            return new Probability(minWindows,
                                   maxWindows,
                                   hasBackDoor,
                                   hasSecondFloor,
                                   hasChimny,
                                   hasGarage,
                                   hasPorch);
        }
    }
}
```

Fields have to be assigned by name, and if you forget which step you are on, the compiler error will tell you:

```
// This will cause an error with a message something like
// "Cannot find symbol method build() in interface MinWindowsStep".
Probability p = Probability.builder()
                           .build();
```

If it turns out that it really is the case that you need to use inheritance, the builder pattern can be adapted to that by having e.g. an abstract build step with multiple implementations.